# operator > < on sql c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, operators, label

I have page.aspx , i have label that shown what is the minimum number (from item table, sql) to open an auoction ...example -  the minimum number value is 5... after i got 5 bids (from table: purchase) - the auoction start and at other lablel shown img: V. while the number of purchase small then 5 - i want to show X image.

i have two tables:

items (id, minNumber)

purchase (id)

when user buy somthing the id value up by one..(example: if i bought banana so i got the id one..after that i buy ball - i got the id 2.)

the question:

how can i use the operators > < = at code behind with the use of sql tables....

i'm very new at sql. i'm usually use LINQ to SQL.. or sql cmnd at code behind.LINQ like:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext myDataContext = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
  var bla = from items in myDataContext.items 
         ..................
    }
```

but how to continue?

i'v been tried:

```
               var Tokef =
                from items in myDataContext.items
                from purchase in myDataContext.purchases
                if (items.Minbuy == purchase.purchaseid) {
                   Image2.Visible = true; }
```

but it doesnt work !!

Comment: try to put some code like what you are thinking with ><= operators that will help us know your query better

Comment: are you looking for the SQL for the query?

Comment: if i will put here the code at comment that will look bad no? i will comment as answer?

Comment: You can put whateven in question.

Comment: i'm edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
 string sql = "Select * From items Where id LIKE '" + ID + "' AND minNumber <>= '" + minNumber+ "'";
```

for Linq to SQL
try something like:`var items = from p in db.items where p.ID == "someValue" AND p.minNumber <>= "somevalue" select p;`